# In GIT how to merge a development branch into master branch by completely overriding the master branch?

Tags: git, github, merge

My master copy has previous files checked in 2years back. My development branch is up-to date. So i want to update my master branch with development branch.

I tried 
git checkout master
git merge -X theirs dev

but it gives an error "can something which we cannot merge"

In the Git web when i tried to create a new pull request, it shows like this "There isn’t anything to compare.
master and master-clean are entirely different commit histories."

Did you mean Origin/Development?

Comment: just `git checkout master` branch and then run `git merge development` ?

Comment: No, that is not what he wants. He wants to throw away the old `master` and start over with current `development`.

Comment: @AnoE That's pretty cryptic, after reading *"... i want to update my master branch with development branch."* I thought he just wants to merge on top of his master

Comment: True, the question could benefit from some spelling/rewording improvement. I'm hanging on the "2 year old master" (which is again an interpretation of mine, I guess) here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, gathering the info from all your comments and your OP, you have this situation:

- A remote (github) repository with a 2-year old, unused, `master` branch and a current `development` branch. Let's call this repository `origin`.
- You want to get completely rid of the remote `master` and replace it by the `development` branch.
- I assume your local working repository is up-to-date with `origin`, i.e. you have committed everything you changed in `development` recently.

So I suggest this procedure:

```
git checkout development ; git pull        # just in case
git branch master development -f
git checkout master
git push origin master -f
```

This will:

- Synchronize your local `development` branch with the remote one, just in case. After this operation, they should be exactly the same. `git status` should tell you this clearly.
- Then you set the `master` to point to the same commit as `development`, locally.
- Then you checkout and push `master` to the remote, overwriting whatever it was before.

After this, `development`, `master`, `origin/development`, `origin/master` all point to the same commit, which is whatever your `development` was beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Just what I was looking for. +1!

Answer (score 1):

Toss current master and use the dev branch?

```
git push origin dev:master --force
```

That will overwrite that *master* branch on the remote with the development branch...

Why would you ever do this though - this will break everyone else working in the code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely delete your master branch: `git branch -D master`

Then re-create it from your development branch : `git checkout -b master development`

Comment: What does "git checkout -b master development" do?

Comment: then how can I revert to latest commit of master branch before merged?

Comment: `git checkout -b master development` does what Marc-Alexandre said; it creates one branch from another. Details see `git help checkout`.

Comment: Haresh, I am not sure I understand your request? if master is not up-to-date, my suggestion is to simply drop it and start it back from the development branch.

Comment: When I'm trying to delete the master branch using "git branch -D master" it gives an error saying "error: branch 'master' not found."

Comment: If you are in a mid-merging state you can simply use `git reset --hard` to reset your master branch before dropping it

Comment: First of all i'm not in mid-merging state. Still i tried to reset using "git reset --hard" and then tried to delete, still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you currently in master branch? If so, checkout your development branch first as it won't let you delete the branch you are currently into

Comment: I'm in the development branch. The error is "error: branch 'master' not found."

Comment: Well then it means your master branch have already been deleted, so it have probably worked the first time you tried

Comment: But still i can see that branch in my dashboard. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: What is your dashboard? The master branch is currently only deleted from your local repository (aka on your computer only). If you have some kind of remote (like github, bitbucket, gitlab, etc), you can go ahead with the creation of master branch locally. `git checkout -b master development`. Then force push it on your remote (assuming it is called origin: `git push -u -f origin master`